# What about CodePro Profiler?

Tags: java, profiling

I just read that http://www.instantiations.com/ is now part of Google and that several tool will be accessible for free => It's really nice.

But what about the CodePro profiler tool ? The only link on the subject I found is the following one: http://download.instantiations.com/ProfilerDoc/continuous/latest/docs/html/index.html and it's not clear for me if it is now free and where download it.

Have you got any news on this subject ?

Manu

Comment: So it's called RAT now, but it still isn't available...

Comment: And there doesn't seem to be any activity. Homepage still dead, forum is completely silent: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/220/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://code.google.com/intl/ru/javadevtools/eclipse-donation-faq.html

Q. When will WindowBuilder and the CodePro Profiler code be made available through open source?
A. Both WindowBuilder and **CodePro Profiler will become Eclipse projects** in the **first half of 2011**. Once each one is set up as a project and downloadable from the Eclipse site, you may access and use its open source code under the Eclipse standard license.

Comment: As it turns out, this never happened.  See Arjan's answer.

Answer (score 5):

CodePro Profiler is still available to existing, paid users. That product has not been re-released free as Google is still evaluating the future of that technology.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Please let me know if you any news about this tool

Answer (score 3):

There was an intention by Google to rebrand CorePro Profiler as *Eclipse Runtime Analysis Tools* (RAT). There was an Eclipse incubation project for it, creating in March 2011:

http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.rat

In April 2012, the project was terminated due to lack of activity (nothing actually happened since project creation).

See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=375133

Answer (score 1):

To complement the [answer of Arjan Tijms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7942242/365237), there exists [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codepro-analytix/lMSeKW6rxuw) from 2012, where Eric Clayberg (one of the original people behind the product) states that

> Google donated both [WindowBuilder and Profiler] to Eclipse in 2010.
>   We (Google) took responsibility on the WindowBuilder project
>   (http://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/), and it successfully transitioned
>   to open source and was part of the Indigo release train last year and
>   soon to be part of Juno this year. The Profile project was lead by the
>   folks who originally collaborated with Instantiations to build the
>   Profiler (OnPositive). For reasons unknown to me, they never got their
>   act together and never completed the Eclipse open source process. That
>   project appears to be dead, so we may try to find another way to
>   release that code - either through Google Code or EclipseLabs.

Answer (score -1):

it seems that Code Pro is available for download from Google's
http://code.google.com/intl/fr/webtoolkit/tools/download-codepro.html

Comment: This is CodePro Analytix, it's not the same tool.

Comment: sorry, I thought you were meaning CodePro Analytix was in the "profiler category"